# How do I create a collapsible list of QCheckBoxes?

Tags: qt, qt4

I would like to make a nested list of QCheckBoxes sort of like a cross between a QtreeWidgetItem and a QCheckBox. From what I have found googling, I can set a flag in a QTreeWidgetItem to make it checkable. So I have this code:

`QTreeWidgetItem *treeWidgetItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(parent);

treeWidgetItem->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);`

However, when the item is displayed in my QTreeWidget, there is no checkbox. The row appears greyed out. How would I make the QTreeWIdgetItem checkable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call setCheckState on your QTreeWidgetItem to ensure that the checkbox appears.  This is from the Qt documentation.

> void QTreeWidgetItem::setCheckState ( int column, Qt::CheckState state)
>
> Sets the item in the given column check state to be the specified state.

Even if you want the checkbox to be off you still have to do this.

Comment: I added the lines: treeWidgetItem->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable), this->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled), and treeWidgetItem->setCheckState(0, Qt::Unchecked). A checkbox appears in my QTreeWIdgetItem. However, when I click on the checkbox, nothing happens. Also, it doesn't seem I can select the item either.

Comment: keep in mind that when you call setFlags you have to merge all the options you want together as follows:  item->setFlags(ItemIsSelectable | ItemIsUserCheckable);  I think you might accidentally have turned off a flag that you need.

Comment: Another question, when I click the checkbox in the QTreeWidgetItem, what signal is emitted?

Comment: There is a signal on the QTreeWidget called itemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem *, int), it passes the item and the column that was changed.  You know the column because that is what is passed when you call setCheckState.  When this signal is triggered, verify in your slot whether the checkbox is checked or not using checkState(int) on your QTreeItemWidget.